# How to use pandas.Series.str.contains with tqdm progress map?

Tags: regex, pandas, tqdm

I'm trying to add a new column to a dataframe (`dfA`) based on values from another dataframe (`dfB`):

```
s = dfA['value'].tolist() 
dfB['value'] = dfB['text_bod'].str.contains('|'.join(s))
```

Can `progress_map` be used with this setup?

`dfB['value] = 'dfB['text_bod].progress_map(func)'`

Or is there some other way tqdm can be implemented?

---

Alternative method using FlashText:

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor

s = dfA['value'].tolist()

processor = KeywordProcessor()
processor.add_keywords_from_list(s)

dfB['value'] = dfB['text_bod'].progress_map(lambda x: processor.extract_keywords(x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not aware of a `str.contains` way, but you can use `progress_map` with a callback that does the exact same thing, but with `re.search`:

```
import re
dfB['value'] = dfB['text_bod'].progress_map(
    lambda x: bool(re.search('|'.join(s), x))
)
```

---

As a function, you can use

```
def extract(x, p):
    m = p.search(x)
    if m:
        return m.groups(0)
    return np.nan

p = re.compile('|'.join(s))
dfB['value'] = dfB['text_bod'].progress_map(lambda x: extract(x, p))
```

This should allow you greater flexibility than a lambda.

Comment: Awesome trying this out rn! Looks like it'll take about 2 hours to run with my test data. Is there a way to get this to output the values from the first dataframe or NaN if DNE instead of True/False?

Comment: @lauren.he You mean something like `dfB['text_bod'].progress_map(lambda x: x if re.search('|'.join(s), x) else np.nan)`?

Comment: Ah almost I think this gives the whole text body in which the value is found. I would like to extract the single matching value from `dfA['value']` and put it into `dfB['value']`

Comment: This seems to work: `test['value'] = test['communication_body'].progress_map(lambda x: re.search('|'.join(s), x).group(0) if re.search('|'.join(s), x) else np.nan)` but `groups(0)` doesn't for multiple matching values hmmm

Comment: @lauren.he You don't need to call `re.search` twice. You can define a function `def foo(x, s):` and implement your code there. lambda isn't critical to have the code work, can be any function.

Comment: I'm not sure how the function would be constructed. Does it involve setting `re.search('|'.join(s), x)` to a variable?

Comment: @lauren.he Sure, take a look at my answer, I've edited to show an example.

Comment: Thanks for providing that! Also I think `re.findall` negates the need for an if statement. Also also just learned about `flashtext` and will include in the post an alternative soln using `extract_keywords`. It was able to complete the matching/extraction task on my sample data within seconds while it took regex hours :O

Comment: @lauren.he you should consider editing this answer or adding a new one with your solution, sounds like it would be worth a read!